# Is 0.40 Alpha score (KR-20) acceptable for a true-false test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, spss, reliability, validity

I have 10 true-false-Idont know test items. I codded correct responses as 1, incorrect ones and dont knows as 0. I got 0.40 alpha score (or KR-20). Do you think that this score is acceptable for such items? ps: I have 400 subjects.

Comment: Why are Incorrect and I Don't Know coded the same? Is it a knowledge assessment so they can be treated as equivalent?

Comment: Yes, it is a knowledge test. I codded in that way because it seems a common approach in the literature. What do you suggest, instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me first address your primary question, and then bring up some other points.

There are very general guidelines on reliability, though these are just guidelines (like p<0.05 is a guideline but there is no objective reason why you shouldn't use 0.04 or 0.10). The classic reference is Nunnally, Jum C, and Ira H. Bernstein. 1978. Psychometric Theory. 2nd ed. New York: McGraw-Hill., which you should be familiar with if you want to report Alpha (not to mention Cronbach's original work, which many are ignorant of). 0.40 is generally not viewed as very reliable, though I have seen researchers make a strong case why it could be in certain applications. In a typical assessment like what you have, though, I wouldn't consider 0.40 very high.

It could (repeat: could) be indicative of problems in the construct you are trying to measure. It could be you have a multidimensional construct you are measuring - you should conduct factor analysis (CFA, not EFA, though EFA could be done first), and do some tests on the factor loadings and correlational structure of the different factors that you may specify, and look at modification indices to look at paths you didn't expect. If this is all new to you, I suggest this could be a good opportunity to learn a little about the technique. It starts out esoteric, but once you understand what is going on it makes a lot of practical sense. It could also mean that what you are measuring is not a very "tight" (or rather, it is diffuse) construct, meaning it is not easy to measure with only 10 items. I've done psychometrics on assessments of very nebulous domains that took a lot of items to reliably measure them. Some would argue there is nothing there - but from a content standpoint (not something quantifiable) experts see it there.

One other thing: KR-20/Alpha make strong assumptions about the correlational structure of your items. Specifically, they assume your items are essentially tau-equivalent - in practical terms, that means the factor loadings on the underlying construct are all equal. That is something you can test in a factor model. If it doesn't hold, KR-20/Alpha will *underestimate* your reliability, and you could use something like McDonald's Omega instead (R's psych package estimates that for you). See McDonald, Roderick P. 1999. Test Theory: A Unified Treatment. New York: Psychology Press, or Raykov, Tenko. 2001. “Bias of Coefficient Afor Fixed Congeneric Measures with Correlated Errors.” Applied Psychological Measurement 25 (1): 69–76.

Comment: Many thanks for clear explanations. I am familiar with CFA and the other procedures that you suggested. I just wanted to bring this issue here to see the reactions of the experts.

Comment: Sure, I hope my answer helped. It is fairly easy to use CFA to test tau-equivalence - simply run the model with loadings unconstrained, and then constrain them to be equal and test the two using a LR test for nested models. If the constrained model fits as good or better, then you have tau-equivalence and can use KR-20/$\alpha$; if not use $\omega$. The psych package in R can do both if you can't figure out how to estimate them yourself.